# Passing query strings from AWS Gateway to sub query in AWS lambda using Python 3.7

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I am writing an AWS lambda function which accepts a query string from a AWS Gateway REST API. The query string variable "myUUID" is then used in the "Where" clause inside a subquery as shown below:

```
myUUID = event["queryStringParameters"]["serviceProviderUUID"]

cursor.execute('Select * From Grower Where growerUUID in ('Select growerUUID from Permission Where serviceProviderUUID = %s,' myUUID)')
```

This statement fails with a "sql sytax error".

Interestingly when the variable is replaced with  hard-coded string "bobsUUID" the statement executes as desired:

```
cursor.execute('Select * From Grower Where growerUUID in ('Select growerUUID from Permission Where serviceProviderUUID = "bobsUUID")')
```

Also,  the subquery alone executes correctly:

```
cursor.execute('Select growerUUID from Permission Where serviceProviderUUID = %s,' myUUID)
```

Is the sub query even possible in an AWS lambda? The documentation is very thin in this area.

Would the walrus operator release in Python 3.8 help here?

#The statement below produced the desired result

cursor.execute('Select * From Grower Where growerUUID in (Select growerUUID from Permission Where serviceProviderUUID = "bobsUUID")')

Comment: please show the complete error mesage

Comment: The quoting of your SQL query as shown in your question results is invalid Python syntax. Are you sure the code you posted here is the same which runs when providing a "bobsUUID"?

Comment: Here is the complete error message produced by the "Monitor" in the AWS console. [ERROR] Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 19)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py" Line 19
        cursor.execute('Select * From Grower Where growerUUID in ('Select growerUUID from Permission Where serviceProviderUUID = %s,' myUUID)')

Comment: True...not exactly the same.  #The statement below produced the desired result
    cursor.execute('Select * From Grower Where growerUUID in (Select growerUUID from Permission Where serviceProviderUUID = "dogmeatUUID")')